# Observable in angular is not working parallel

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I have a code in which i am calling an observable function using subscribe.
I am expecting it to run parallel but it is running in sequence.

makedownloadData() is function to store all variables of "showData" list variable in different variable let's say "downloadData". function takes lots of time to copy all the variables to downloadData and further processing. So I thought of calling this function using observable/subscribe technique so that it should run parallerly without causing delay in current sequence but it is running in sequence only. No enhancement.

First method (without observable)

Calling the function

```
this.downloadData=this.makeDownloadData() //This step is taking lot's of time as function respond late. 
console.log("print after function call")
```

Function to be called

```
public makeDownloadData() {
var main_data = this.showData;
var down_data:any = [];
for (var i=0; i<main_data.length; i++){
  var element: String = "";
  var newDate = new Date(main_data[i]["@timestamp"]);
  element = element.concat(this.convertDateToLocalFormat(newDate)+" ");
  element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["cu_hostname"])+" ");
  element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["log_agent"])+".");
  element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["log_level"])+" ");
  element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["app_name"])+": ");
  element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["log_message"])+" ");
  down_data.push(element.concat("\n"));
}
return down_data;
```

}

Output:

```
//Execution of function
"print after function call"
```

Second method (With observable)

Importing the requirements

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'
```

Calling an observable function.

```
this.makeDownloadData().subscribe(response => {
   console.log("Expected to print after") //This should be run in parallel and must printed after upcoming statement as this function is taking time to respond.
   console.log(response); //Expected to print after 
},
error => {
  console.log("Did not got response")
});

console.log("Expected to print before")
```

Function to be called

```
public makeDownloadData(): Observable<any> {
var main_data = this.showData;
var down_data:any = [];
for (var i=0; i<main_data.length; i++){
  var element: String = "";
  var newDate = new Date(main_data[i]["@timestamp"]);
  element = element.concat(this.convertDateToLocalFormat(newDate)+" ");
  element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["cu_hostname"])+" ");
  element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["log_agent"])+".");
  element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["log_level"])+" ");
  element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["app_name"])+": ");
  element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["log_message"])+" ");
  down_data.push(element.concat("\n"));
}
return Observable.of(down_data)
```

}

Output :

```
"Expected to print after"
Printing response
"Expected to print before"
```

Expected Output :

```
"Expected to print before"
"Expected to print after"
Printing response
```

I want to use observable for parallel execution. Kindly help. if anything unclear than i will modify the question to make it more clear.
Thanks

Comment: hello, your code seems ok to me and should work. How much time does the makeDownloadData method takes ? because if there is no data it could finish before the second console.log

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response. "makeDownloadData" takes approx. 10 seconds to return. So till that time also it will not print further line and wait for function to finish the execution. After 10 seconds it will print both line one after another in sequence as written in code.

Comment: Until you return your observable, makeDownloadData() is completely synchronous. You can try something like setTimeout(() => this.downloadData=this.makeDownloadData()). This will put the function at the end of the line in the event loop (is there are no setTimeouts waiting with time set) and your current method will proceed. But it will take time to execute when the event loop selects it to run, and if you're doing something at that moment, it'll freeze util the function ends. If that computation is taking really long time, you may consider using a webworker...

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. your function `makeDownloadData()` is not an observable, it just *returns one observable* (the code that is taking time is before the return statement)
2. not all observables are asynchronous by default (in fact, just a few of them are really asynchronous by default)

The following code has a completely asynchronous observable (thanks to the `asyncScheduler` parameter on the `of` function - without it `of` is a synchronous function that returns an observable):

```
const source = of('Hello, subscriber', asyncScheduler).pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('Inside observable')),
  map(x => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
      for(let j = 0; j < 1; j++);

    return x;
  })
);
console.log('After observable')

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

By saying this is asynchronous, I mean that `After observable` will be in the console immediately. After some time you will see `'Inside observable'` followed by `'Hello, subscriber'`.

If you remove the `asyncScheduler` of the observable, you will wait for some time and will see the same sequence (`'After observable', 'Inside observable', 'Hello, subscriber'`), but all the code would be blocked until the loop inside the observable finished and, **just after that**, you would see the three strings being printed on the console **almost at the same time**. Take a look at this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-stackoverflow-556297976433166?file=index.ts

#### So you can try this:

```
makeDownloadData(): any { // <== doesn't need to return an observable
  var main_data = this.showData;
  var down_data:any = [];
  for (var i=0; i<main_data.length; i++){
    var element: String = "";
    var newDate = new Date(main_data[i]["@timestamp"]);
    element = element.concat(this.convertDateToLocalFormat(newDate)+" ");
    element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["cu_hostname"])+" ");
    element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["log_agent"])+".");
    element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["log_level"])+" ");
    element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["app_name"])+": ");
    element = element.concat(String(main_data[i]["log_message"])+" ");
    down_data.push(element.concat("\n"));
  }
  return down_data // <== this doesn't need to return an observable
}
```

**Update**: I replaced `of(this.makeDownloadData())` by `of(1)`, otherwise it'll take the same time to create the operator that was needed to run the function in the original problem. Then you can map it to the desired function.

```
import { of, asyncScheduler } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

this.downloadData=of(1, asyncScheduler)
    .pipe(map(() => this.makeDownloadData());
```

Using `of` here is not the best approach for creating an observable, but it's the  most clear, by far, as I need the `asyncScheduler` to make it asynchronous. The '1' as the first parameter is a dumb data. You can use anything. The `of` function needs a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have tried your method but output is still same. It is acting as normal function call only (sequentially). May be something is still missing.

Comment: @ShubhankGupta, you're right. you cannot call your function directly inside `of` operator, or it will expect it to run in order to create the operator.  You must pipe some fast creation observable and map it to your function. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to call the subscribe method that is your before print after the subscribe get data then call the normal method that is your after print method so now you can get the correct answer i thing it will help you any clarification please rely this answer

Answer (score 0):

Unlike with promises, where code like

```
Promise.resolve("one").then(console.log);
console.log("two");
```

results in "two" being printed before "one", observables aren't async in nature, just like callbacks aren't. So `of("one").subscribe(console.log)` will print immediately, not after the end of the event loop tick.

Here's a longer lecture:
https://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/rxjs-subjects-emit-synchronous-values

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response. As i am new to this topic. Can you explain it considering my example? I am unable to get what you are trying to say with your answer.

Comment: Doesn't matter how long your `makeDownloadData()` function takes. By subscribing to it, you call the function, and `makeDownloadData()` blocks the rest of the script. Further lines, like `console.log("Expected to print before")`, will be executed when `makeDownloadData` is done.
To _not_ wait for it, you'd need to make `makeDownloadData` do something asynchronous - jump outside the JavaScript thread, in fact - like a HTTP call, or a setTimeout, or something like that.